# How to construct or create documents and pass them to other functions in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I have written following code and when I create a document and passing it to it I'm getting empty array. User is already created in DB. Please help me.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var userobj1 = {};
    userobj1.name = 'joe';
    userobj1.age = '29'
var newuser = new User(userobj1);
     userobj1.save(function (err, user) {
        if (err) console.log(err)
        return user
    }).then(function (user) {
        console.log(user)
    })
}
```

Comment: can you add complete code?

Comment: put here the complete code please.